# Read a text file and convert into nested dict of dict with same keys using python

Tags: python

I want python to read text file and create a nested dict. 
I have these datas in a text file abc.

> 'name':'a', 'age':11, 'blood group':'A+ve', 'mob num':123456,
>   'address':'12,abc street'
>
> 'name':'b', 'age':12, 'blood group':'A-ve', 'mob num':124,
>   'address':'112,abc street'

I have read the text file but I dont know how to proceed. I'm a beginner in python.

```
with open ("text.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

My output should look like

> {Name:a,b Age:11,12 { blood group: A+ve,A -ve {Mob num: 123456,124
>   {Address: 12 abc street, 112 abc street}}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will allow you to write each row to a list as a dictionary:

```
dicts_from_file = []
with open ("text.txt",'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        row = "{" + row + "}"
        dicts_from_file.append(eval(row))
    print dicts_from_file
```

Then iterate through each dictionary writing to a master dict:

```
master_dict = {}
for dict in dicts_from_file:
    for x in dictionary:
        if x in master_dict:
            master_dict[x].append(dictionary[x])
        else:
            master_dict[x] = [dictionary[x]]
print(master_dict)
```

This doesn't have the issue with the addresses either.

## EDIT

Data_Structure =  {"Name": [], "Age":[], "Other":{ "blood group": [], More: {"Mob num": [], "Address": []}}}}

Say I want to write to the 3rd nested dictionary (Mob Number) you would say Data_Structure["Other"]["More"]["Mob num"].append('040010909'). The original syntax doesn't make sense because you have to have a key for each sub-dictionary.

## Final Edit

Here's a bit of code to show you how the matching of keys might work. It's not super elegant but it works:

```
some_dict = {"name": [], "age": [],  "other": {"mob num":[],"address":[]}}

with open("hello.txt", 'r') as input_file:
    for row in input_file:
        row = "{" + row + "}"
        this_rows_dict = eval(row)
        for key in this_rows_dict:
            if key == 'name':
                some_dict['name'].append(this_rows_dict[key])
            elif key == 'age':
                some_dict['age'].append(this_rows_dict[key])
            elif key == 'mob num':
                some_dict["other"]["mob num"].append(this_rows_dict[key])
            elif key == "address":
                some_dict["other"]["address"].append(this_rows_dict[key])
            else:
                print("Unknown Key: {}".format(key))
print some_dict
```

Comment: It doesnt groups values for same keys

Comment: It does if you run both pieces of code. The first imports all as dictionaries, the second groups by key.

Comment: I need them to be in nested dict but they are nested list of dict

Comment: Wait I see your original suggestion 2 seconds

Comment: So why do you want it to be nested dictionaries? Why is blood group a subdictionary of name and age? Surely you should have some ID value and then have all of these subsequent values as entries to that dictionary. So it would be: {ID: 929290 {"Name" : "Bob", "Blood Type": "AB+"}}. In my version all of the values for the same line are at the same index and are parallel, is that not ideal?

Comment: Im trying to practice with nested dicts. Is it possible to store each key value pair of text file as a dict and then update them?? like d1=name,age. d2=blood group d3=mob num d4=address and then update them. or match dict keys with text file keys

Comment: You can initialise the dictionary as {Name: [] Age:[] { blood group: [] {Mob num: [] {Address: []}}}}. Once you have a list of dictionaries (as per the first piece of code) you can loop through and with a series of if statements write to the appropriate dictionary. For an example see my edited answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was just writing it out.

Comment: Is it possible to match keys??

Comment: If by matching keys you mean as we read in the file, check whether the key is in the dictionary and write accordingly then yes. So you would iterate through each dictionary and when you say `for key in dictionary` you will get each key. You can use this to identify where the data should be written to. In my original example this is used to identify when a key already exists in the dictionary `if x in master_dict`

Comment: yes. I will iterate through each line of file and if the dict key matches with the keys in file, then values should be updated so that it will be a nested dict. Can you write the sample program so that it will be easier for me to understand?

Comment: Yeah no worries, I've added it, can you mark it as the right answer if it fits your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might be sufficient to give you a kick start:

```
data = dict()
data['name'], data['age'],data['group'],data['num'],data['address'] = [],[],[],[],[] 

with open ("text.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key_val_pairs = line.split(',')
        for kv_pair in key_val_pairs:
            k_v = kv_pair.split(':')
            key = k_v[0]
            val = k_v[1]
            data[key].append(val)
```

Comment: The address is being split because it has a comma in it (something I had issues with when trying to work with this)

Comment: Yeah, something needs to be done for handling that exception but basic structure would be this. Maybe you can suggest some changes in my answer for handling that.

Comment: Can you get me the solution for the above problem without considering address

Comment: Is it possible to create dict keys and then match dict keys with the keys in text file??

Comment: If you are not considering addresses then above is the right solution. Yes, you can do that with a dictionary.

Comment: Can you explain how to match dict keys with keys in text file?

Comment: dict objects has method called `keys()` which gives you the list of all the keys in the dictionary. Then, you can match it with anything you want.